# How to return interface key types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have `interface`

```
interface Some {
  key1: string
  key2: number
}
```

There is a function.

```
const fn = (key: keyof Some) => {
   return <Some>someObject[key]
}
```

Сan I get the return type by string key?

```
fn(‘key1’) // can ts know that it will return `string`?
fn(‘key2’) // can ts know that it will return `number`?
```

UPDATED:

Thank you @captain-yossarian for the answer! Now I have a bit extended case.

```
export const getConfig = <T extends EntityInitialConfig, K extends keyof T> (key?: K) => {
  let config: T = window.someObject

  return key ? config[key] : config
}

getConfig('clientKey') // ts shows `string | EntityInitialConfig`
```

And it's a problem because just need only `string`. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume You are looking for next solution:

```js
const fn = <T extends unknown, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): T[K] => {
    return obj[key]
}

const result = fn({ name: 'John', age: 42 }, 'name') // string
const result2 = fn({ name: 'John', age: 42 }, 'age') // number
```

**[UPDATE]**
Your function expects key argument to be undefined, you should defenitely provide default value.

If You are Ok with default value, then you should add function overloadings.

```js
interface EntityInitialConfig {
    age: number;
    name: string;
}

const config: EntityInitialConfig = { age: 42, name: 'John' };

interface GetConfig {
    (key: undefined): EntityInitialConfig['name'] // it is kinda default value
    <K extends keyof EntityInitialConfig>(key: K): EntityInitialConfig[K]

}
export const getConfig: GetConfig = <K extends keyof EntityInitialConfig>(key?: K) => {
    return key ? config[key] : config
}

const x = getConfig('age') // ts shows number
```

P.S. I'm not sure if it is correct syntax: `return <Some>someObject[key]`

Comment: Thx you for the answer. It helped me. I extended the question. Try to help me again plz =)

Comment: Thanks for your kind words!